# What does /24 means in nmap scanning?

Tags: nmap

I have just started learning about the use of `nmap` and while doing so, I am unable to find much information on a particular command.

This is the command I am using: `nmap -sP 192.168.100.0/24` to scan for the list of connected devices on the network.

While the ip address used is the subnet ip, I am having trouble understanding what `/24` does.

Can someone kindly share any insights to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

/24 specifies the netmask to use -- 24 bits in this case, so a mask of 255.255.255.0.  So it will scan all addresses from 192.168.100.0 to 192.168.100.255

Answer (score 0):

`/24` is the prefix length used to indicate the number of network bits of an IP address.

Refer this article from Cisco: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html

Also, before starting with nmap, you must have basic knowledge about computer networks to understand different types of scan.